# Why value property of input object does not hold value?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, keyboard-events

In first approach, using `KeyBoardEvent` instance, below event handler `f` **COULD** retrieve the character after keyboard key press, as shown below:

```
<form action="#" id="sampForm" >
            <input id='charInput' type='text'>
            <p id="KeyData">Key press data here</p>
</form><br>

document.getElementById('charInput').onkeypress = f;

function f(event) {
  var char = getChar(event || window.event)
  if (!char) return false; // Special Key Pressed
          document.getElementById('keyData').innerHTML = char + " was pressed";
                          return true;
}       

function getChar(event) {
  // event.which returns the key pressed
  if (event.which == null) {
        // Return the char if not a special character
        return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); // IE
  } else if (event.which!=0 && event.charCode!=0) {
        return String.fromCharCode(event.which);   // Other Browsers
  } else {
        return null; // Special Key Pressed
  }
}
```

---

In second approach, using `value` property of `HTMLInputElement` instance, below call back function `f` **COULD NOT** retrieve the character after key press,

```
<form action="#" id="sampForm" >
            <input id='charInput' type='text'>
            <p id="KeyData">Key press data here</p>
</form><br>

document.getElementById('charInput').onkeypress = f;

function f(){
    document.getElementById('KeyData').innerHTML =  document.getElementById('charInput').value  + 'is pressed';
    return true;
}
```

---

In second approach, Why `document.getElementById('charInput').value` is empty string, when I press first keyboard character? How does this problem get resolved in event handling approach?

*Note: w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html --An object which implements the Event interface is generally passed as the first parameter to an event handler. In the above code, I have assigned callback instead of event hanfler in second approach*. Because there is no documentation that says that `onkeypress` property value MUST be event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onkeypress`event occurs when the user presses a key on the keyboard. At that point in time, the key value that the user entered is *not* put in the textbox yet. So the first time you enter a key,  `document.getElementId('charInput').value` returns the *current* value of the textbox which is empty. The next time you press a key, it will show the first value entered in the text box. Please note that `document.getElementId('charInput').value` shows the current value of the text box and not the key character pressed. Furthermore, there should be a opening bracked after function `f()`, so it should be:

```
function f() {
    document.getElementById('KeyData').innerHTML = document.getElementById('charInput').value  + 'is the content of charInput';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: OK, what is the intricacy that, when you press key second time, it will show the first value in second approach? How does this work with first  approach?

Comment: 'document.getElementById('charInput').value ' does not show the value that was pressed, it shows the current value of the text box. So when there is one character in the text box and you press a key again, it shows that one character.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, when there is one character in the text box and you press a key again, it shows that one character. What makes `document.getElementById('charInput').value` to show first character immediately after pressing second character? this is my question

Comment: The reason is that onKeyPress happens before the character is put in the textbox. So at the moment function f is executed the character just entered is not put in the text box yet (it will be thereafter).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the opening bracket of the `function f`

```
function f(){
 // your code
}
```

Comment: `{` was type, while posting query, here is the problem [code](http://jsfiddle.net/7cr2nyqo/8/)

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. The function f() is missing a parentheses '{'. Also make sure that you have this code surrounded by `<script>` tags. Also use onkeyup instead of onkeypress.

Comment: Use onkeyup instead of onkeypress. This event occurs after you 'un-press' the key, which ensures that the value was added in the input field. In your first case, you got the key from the event object itself. But the event onkeypress alltogether, occurs before the value is entered in the input field, so that's why the value was empty. To see the difference, check this link out [link](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx)